# ffmpeg video trimming without freezed starting frames

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, freeze, multimedia

I am using the following commands for cutting videos using ffmpeg. However, they are presenting weird results.

When I am using the following command, the output video has its frames freezed for starting 1 or 2 seconds and plays smooth later.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 30 -t 45 out.mp4
```

Whereas, this commands solves the problem of freezed frames but seeking is not accurate as I am using *-ss* parameter before input.

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 45 out.mp4
```

I am looking for help that will let me come up with a solution that will accurately clip the video without freezing frames.

Comment: Not possible without transcoding. See http://superuser.com/a/1168028/114058

Comment: in any way can I clip exact 30 seconds video when seeking doesn't matter but the start point must not coincide with I-Frame

Comment: @Mulvya how can I do transcoding to acheive above thing.

Comment: Drop the `-vcodec copy` in the 2nd command.

Comment: I tried but output is completely black with audio only.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full, uncut command line output for the commands. (Also the last one you said you've tried.)